# Swift: Bool if true, doesn't display image

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uitableview

I'm a beginner so please be patient explaining, Thanks.

So, basically I have a bool column in parse and I want to display an image if it's false and don't display anything if its true.

here are my codes:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reqTodaysCell      
        let cellDataParse: PFObject = self.dataparse.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        var newReadQuery = PFQuery(className: "request")
        newReadQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {

                    if object["reqRead"] as! Bool == true {

                        myCell.isRead.image = nil //here is where I say pic to be nil but what happens is that if the first one is true then it will remove the pic for all of them.
        // and if its not true it should display the pic

                    } else {

        myCell.isRead.image = UIImage(named: "newReq")
                        print("user not read")

                    }


                }
            }
        })
```

If I don't explain properly please let me know and I will try my best to explain again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an ideal use case for a ternary operator. As per my example below, you use the ? : syntax following a Bool, if the bool is true it will return the first case and if it's false it will return the second case.

```
newReadQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {

              let reqRead = object["reqRead"] as! Bool

              cell.image.image = reqRead ? nil : UIImage(named: "newReq")

            }
        }
    })
```

**UPDATE**

The above may not have worked as the Parse call might not be completed before the cells are loaded.

Create a global variable (outside of any function):

```
var reqRead = [Bool]()
```

In ViewDidLoad you can create an array of the bools.

```
    var newReadQuery = PFQuery(className: "request")
 newReadQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if let objects = objects {

        for object in objects {

          reqRead.append(object["reqRead"] as! Bool)

        }
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

Then in your CellForRow:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reqTodaysCell      
    let cellDataParse: PFObject = self.dataparse.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

cell.image.image = reqRead[indexPath.row] ? nil : UIImage(named: "newReq")

return cell

}
```

There's a possibility that it will try to populate the cells before the array is loaded but let me know if this works for you.

Comment: the above method has the same result like the one i used

Comment: Ok this could be a network issue, I'll try a different solution

Comment: maybe and please let me know if any idea hits you thanks :)

Comment: oh my god you are  a life saver thanks it worked !! ^^

Comment: That's great to hear, glad I could help! :]

Answer (score 0):

```
   if object["reqRead"] as! Bool == false {

                    myCell.isRead.image = nil 
                    myCell.isRead.hidden = false

                } else {

                    myCell.isRead.hidden = true

                }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work... tried changing hidden to true and the other one false no difference ...

Comment: check if that loop executing  or not and do myCell.isRead.hidden = false after -  let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reqTodaysCell

Comment: i do see the picture in the beginning but then all disappears which is wrong. I have three objects and 2 of them are true and one is false but doesnt show them like i want to...